# Group K-fold with target stratification

Tags: scikit-learn, pandas, cross-validation

I have a pd.DataFrame

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'person': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
    'group': [10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30],
    'target': [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
})
```

I want to split df into train and test by **group** several times (K-Fold), so train and test contains examples from mutually exclusive **group** subsets. For example, if test contains examples from groups [10, 20] test should contain examples only from group [30]. I also want to keep stratification by target. So target distribution is also considered for groups subsets creation. How is it possible? Didn't find anything in scikit-learn that may help.

In practice I have a df with about 500k rows, 2.5k different persons, 30 groups and following target distribution [image: target]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use both groups and stratification, it seems that you should write your own code. Note that **you will inevitably loose samples in training and/or in testing set** (unless you are lucky).

One way of achieving it is to:

1. do your split by groups (you could use the [GroupKFold method](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold.html) from `sklearn`)
2. check the distribution of the targets in training/testing sets.
3. randomly remove targets in training or testing set to balance the distributions.

*Note*: It is possible that a group disappear using such algorithm. You might prefer to not randomly remove the targets when balancing the training/testing sets.

---

Here is a sample code

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupKFold

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'person': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
    'group': [10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30],
    'target': [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
})

X = df['person']
y = df['target']
groups = df['group'].values
group_kfold = GroupKFold(n_splits=3)
group_kfold.get_n_splits(X, y, groups)

# First split by groups
for train_index, test_index in group_kfold.split(X, y, groups):
    print("Groups split: TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    y_train_grouped, y_test_grouped = y[train_index], y[test_index]

    final_train_index = []
    final_test_index = []
    # Then balance the distributions for each target
    for target in df['target'].unique():
        target_train_index = y_train_grouped[y_train_grouped == target].index.tolist()
        target_test_index = y_test_grouped[y_test_grouped == target].index.tolist()
        n_training = len(target_train_index)
        n_testing = len(target_test_index)
        print("Target:" + str(target) + " - n_training:" + str(n_training) + " - n_testing:" + str(n_testing) +
              " | target_train_index:" + str(target_train_index) + " - target_test_index:" + str(target_test_index))
        
        # Shuffle to remove randomly
        np.random.shuffle(target_train_index)
        np.random.shuffle(target_test_index)
        
        # Check if we need to remove samples from training or testing set
        if n_training > n_testing:
            while n_training > n_testing:
                target_train_index.pop(0)
                n_training = len(target_train_index)
        if n_training < n_testing:
            while n_training < n_testing:
                target_test_index.pop(0)
                n_testing = len(target_test_index)
        
        # Append new indexes to global train/test indexes
        final_train_index.append(target_train_index)
        final_test_index.append(target_test_index)

    # Flatten for readability
    final_train_index = [item for sublist in final_train_index for item in sublist]
    final_test_index = [item for sublist in final_test_index for item in sublist]
    print("FINAL split: TRAIN:", final_train_index," TEST:", final_test_index, "\n")
```

---

**EDIT**

Using stratified cross-validation **seems not** to be **mandatory** (see links below), so you might reconsider using it.

You might find this links usefuls:

- [Why use stratified cross validation? Why does this not damage variance related benefit?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117643/why-use-stratified-cross-validation-why-does-this-not-damage-variance-related-b)
- [Understanding stratified cross-validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/understanding-stratified-cross-validation)
- [A study of cross-validation and bootstrap for accuracy estimation and model selection](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/%7Ejtian/cs573/Papers/Kohavi-IJCAI-95.pdf)

Regarding over/undersampling, I think it is hard to answer without more details of the data distribution and how imbalanced your classes are.

Comment: Thank you. Should I consider over/under sampling as a better approach?

Comment: I have just updated my answer, hope it helps.